# Why am I not able to use stopwatch.Restart()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call `Restart()` on a stopwatch instance but am getting the following error when trying to call it:

> Assets/Scripts/Controls/SuperTouch.cs(22,59): error CS1061: Type
>   `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch' does not contain a definition for`
>   Restart' and no extension method `Restart' of type`
>   System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Controls
{

    public class SuperTouch
    {
            public Vector2 position { get { return points [points.Count - 1]; } }
            public float duration { get { return (float)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds; } }
            public float distance;
            public List<Vector2> points = new List<Vector2> ();

            public Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch ();

            public void Reset ()
            {
                    points.Clear ();
                    distance = 0;
                    stopwatch.Restart ();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `System.Diagnostics` in your project references?

Comment: Are you using Framework 3.5 by any chance?

Comment: Like @NadiaChibrikova said, if you are using Framework version less than 4 you dont have the `Restart()` method for `StopWatch`. You will have to do `StopWatch.Reset()` and then `StopWatch.Start()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using `.Net Framework 3.5` or below where the `Restart` method of `Stopwatch` doesnt exists.

If you want to replicate the same behavior you can do it like this.

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
// do some things here
// output the elapse if needed
watch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); // creates a new Stopwatch instance 
                              // and starts it upon creation
```

The StartNew static method already exists on `.Net Framework 2.0`

More details about StartNew method here: [Stopwatch.StartNew Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.startnew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Or alternatively, you can create an extension method for yourself.

Here is a mockup and usage.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void Restart(this Stopwatch watch)
    {
        watch.Stop();
        watch.Start();
    }
}
```

Consume like

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Restart(); // an extension method
    }
}
```

Comment: Ruud's answer is good too but this one reminded me of how I can use extension methods to add the missing method.

Comment: Stop followed by Start won't reset the elapsed time. Should be Reset followed by Start.

Answer (score 10):

I'm guessing you use pre 4.0 framework, which means you'll have to use `Reset` and `Start` instead of `Restart`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling multiple methods (prone to human error), use an extension method.

```
  public static class StopwatchExtensions
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Support for .NET Framework <= 3.5
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sw"></param>
    public static void Restart(this Stopwatch sw)
    {
      sw.Stop();
      sw.Reset();
      sw.Start();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Unity Engine uses a subset of .NET 2.0. As others have stated, `Restart` was added in .NET 4.0. [This useful page](http://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html) shows all of .NET functions that you can safely use. As you can see, `Start` and `Reset` are present.